# Adding new.line in future price?

Tags: pine-script

I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out.. so here I am.

**1.**
I want to make a script to plot lines and text like this:
https://gyazo.com/250560130c661044d2c37106b9a367fe

I got the lines for historical price figured out, but for future, I'm starting to think it's not possible with lines? I have tried so much.

**2.**
Is it possible to put text on vertical line directly in line.new? Or make a label.new and rotate it 90 degrees?

**3.**
How could I get the texts to be at the same level above/below the bars? Right now I use low[30]

```css
//@version=4
study("TEST nr 032",overlay=true)
fromHour = 00
t1 = timestamp("GMT-4", year, month, dayofmonth, fromHour, 00, 00)
t2 = t1
timeIsOk = (time >= t1) and (time <= t2)

if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
    line.new(bar_index, low * .9999, bar_index, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.blue, line.style_solid, 1)
    var label1 = label.new(bar_index, low[30], text="Monday", style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label1, 0)
    label.set_xloc(label1, time, xloc.bar_time)

if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
    line.new(bar_index, low * .9999, bar_index, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.blue, line.style_solid, 1)
    var label2 = label.new(bar_index, low[30], text="Tuesday", style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label2, 0)
    label.set_xloc(label2, time, xloc.bar_time)

if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
    line.new(bar_index, low * .9999, bar_index, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.blue, line.style_solid, 1)
    var label3 = label.new(bar_index, low[30], text="Wednesday", style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label3, 0)
    label.set_xloc(label3, time, xloc.bar_time)

if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
    line.new(bar_index, low * .9999, bar_index, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.blue, line.style_solid, 1)
    var label4 = label.new(bar_index, low[30], text="Tursday", style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label4, 0)
    label.set_xloc(label4, time, xloc.bar_time)

if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
    line.new(bar_index, low * .9999, bar_index, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.blue, line.style_solid, 1)
    var label5 = label.new(bar_index, low[30], text="Friday", style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label5, 0)
    label.set_xloc(label5, time, xloc.bar_time)


fromHour2 = 18
t3 = timestamp("GMT-4", year, month, dayofmonth, fromHour2, 00, 00)
t4 = t3
timeIsOk2 = (time >= t3) and (time <= t4)

if timeIsOk2 and dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday
    line.new(bar_index, low * .9999, bar_index, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.red, line.style_solid, 1)
    var label7 = label.new(bar_index, low[30], text="Sunday", style=label.style_none)
    label.set_x(label7, 0)
    label.set_xloc(label7, time, xloc.bar_time)
```

Thank you so much for your time, I really apperience it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you on your way. If you have questions on the code, just ask.

What we are doing is keeping 2 sets of lines and drawings: one for the bar where the daily condition is detected and one for the future, one week ahead.

Text can't be rotated in Pine, so we need to print it one letter per line. The text is printed one bar past the line, but when you zoom in/out, its position will vary relative to the line. Can't do much about that.

```
//@version=4
study("TEST nr 032",overlay=true)
fromHour = 00
t1 = timestamp("GMT-4", year, month, dayofmonth, fromHour, 00, 00)
t2 = t1
timeIsOk = (time >= t1) and (time <= t2)

// ————— Calculates the chart's normal time between bars.
f_chartTimeInterval() =>
    var _timeDelta = 10e15
    // Maintain the smallest interbar time value in the dataset, which should correspond to the chart's interval.
    _timeDelta := min(time - nz(time[1]), _timeDelta)

// ————— Calculates a time offset (+/-) which is a multiple of the chart's interval for use with drawing functions.
f_timeAtIntervalMultiple(_mult) =>
    // _mult ("series int"): +/- number of time intervals in the future/past to be calculated.
    int(time + f_chartTimeInterval() * _mult)

// ————— Calculates a +/- time offset from the current bar's time.
f_timeFromBar(_qty, _units) =>
    // _qty   : the +/- number of units of offset required. A "series float" can be used but it will cast to a "series int".
    // _units : string containing one of the 6 allowed time units (the `f_chartTimeUnits()` can be used to supply the current chart's resolution).
    _year   = year        + (_units == "years"   ? int(_qty) : 0)
    _month  = month       + (_units == "months"  ? int(_qty) : 0)
    _day    = dayofmonth  + (_units == "days"    ? int(_qty) : 0)
    _hour   = hour        + (_units == "hours"   ? int(_qty) : 0)
    _minute = minute      + (_units == "minutes" ? int(_qty) : 0)
    _second = second      + (_units == "seconds" ? int(_qty) : 0)
    timestamp(_year, _month, _day, _hour, _minute, _second)

// ————— Draws a text label.
f_drawText(_label, _x, _y, _t, _c) =>
    if na(_label)
        label.new(_x, _y, text = _t, xloc = xloc.bar_time, textcolor = _c, style = label.style_none)
    else
        label.set_xy(_label, _x, _y)
        _label

// ————— Draws a line.
f_drawLine(_line, _x, _c) =>
    if na(_line)
        line.new(_x, low * .9999, _x, high * 1.0001, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, _c, line.style_solid, 1)
    else
        line.set_xy1(_line, _x, low * .9999)
        line.set_xy2(_line, _x, high * 1.0001)
        _line

// ————— Processes one day of lines and labels.
f_doOneDay(_y, _day, _txtColor, _lineColor) =>
    timeInOneWeek = f_timeFromBar(7, "days")
    var line _lineCurrent = f_drawLine(line(na), time, _lineColor)
    var line _lineFuture  = f_drawLine(line(na), time, _lineColor)
    _lineCurrent := f_drawLine(_lineCurrent, time, _lineColor)
    _lineFuture  := f_drawLine(_lineFuture, timeInOneWeek, _lineColor)
    var label _labelCurrent = f_drawText(label(na), time, _y, _day, _txtColor)
    var label _labelFuture  = f_drawText(label(na), time, _y, _day, _txtColor)
    _labelCurrent := f_drawText(_labelCurrent, int(time + f_chartTimeInterval()), _y, _day, _txtColor)
    _labelFuture  := f_drawText(_labelFuture, int(timeInOneWeek + f_chartTimeInterval()), _y, _day, _txtColor)

y         = highest(close, 500)[1]
textColor = color.gray
lineColor = color.blue
txtMon    = "M\no\nn\nd\na\ny"
txtTue    = "T\nu\ne\ns\nd\na\ny"
txtWed    = "W\ne\nd\nn\ne\ns\nd\na\ny"
txtThu    = "T\nh\nu\nr\ns\nd\na\ny"
txtFri    = "F\nr\ni\nd\na\ny"
txtSun    = "S\nu\nn\nd\na\ny"

if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
    f_doOneDay(y, txtMon, textColor, lineColor)
else if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
    f_doOneDay(y, txtTue, textColor, lineColor)
else if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
    f_doOneDay(y, txtWed, textColor, lineColor)
else if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
    f_doOneDay(y, txtThu, textColor, lineColor)
else if timeIsOk and dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
    f_doOneDay(y, txtFri, textColor, lineColor)

fromHour2 = 18
t3 = timestamp("GMT-4", year, month, dayofmonth, fromHour2, 00, 00)
t4 = t3
timeIsOk2 = (time >= t3) and (time <= t4)

if timeIsOk2 and dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday
    f_doOneDay(y, txtSun, color.red, color.red)
```

[image]